# How to apply .dt.year to a series of type datetime.date?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, python-datetime

For a series of type datetime.datetime I can just type .dt.year to retrieve an array of years. However, my data does not have hours, minutes etc. I want to use the datetime.date object instead, but if I then try to access the year I get an error.

Code example:

```
dateAndTime = datetime.datetime(2023,1,1)
dateWithoutTime = datetime.date(2023,1,1)

dateAndTime.dt.year     # returns array of years
dateWithoutTime.dt.year # AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

However, `dateWithoutTime[0].year` does return the first year of the series. How do I get an array of years?

Comment: when I run your code I get _"AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'dt'"_ ...it seems like maybe the `dateAndTime` on the third line is different (pandas object?) from the one you define on the first line?  please show your actual code or give more details

Comment: if you want to use `.dt` (dt namespace methods), you'll have to use the pandas datetime64 dtype. pandas has no built-in date type, just datetime. Therefore, `.dt` is not available for Series of the vanilla Python datetime.date type.